# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AmazonProducts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem trying to save an entity which is a foreign key to a parent object..

i have an amazonProduct entity.  And an AmazonCompetitivePrice entity which is a virtual list on the amazonProduct like so :

```
public class AmazonProduct
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public virtual int ASIN

        public virtual IList<AmazonProductCompetitivePrice> amazonProductCompetitivePrices = new List<AmazonProductCompetitivePrice>();
}
```

So i have a AmazonProduct which i retrieve from the database, and then add a new AmazonProductCompetitivePrice to the amazonProduct.

But when i try save this, I get the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AmazonProducts'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AmazonProducts'.\r\nThe statement
>   has been terminated

It looks like its not realising that my AmazonProduct is already in the database, and its trying to save a new one but the primary key already exists!

I used the fluent API to map the foreign key like so:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmazonProduct>()
                    .HasMany(pl => pl.AmazonProductCompetitivePrices)
                    .WithOptional(p => p.AmazonProduct)
                    .Map(c => c.MapKey("ASIN"));
```

Anyone know whats wrong with this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
object retrieval:

```
 using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkInventory())
            {
                using (var amazRepo = new AmazonProductRepository(uow))
                {
                    return amazRepo.FindByAsin(ASIN);
                }
            }
 public AmazonProduct FindByAsin(string asin)
        {
            return context.AmazonProducts.Include(x => x.AmazonLowestOfferListings).Include(x => x.AmazonMyPrices).Include(x => x.AmazonProductCompetitivePrices).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ASIN == asin);
        }
```

That gets me the AmazonProduct.. then the save:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkInventory())
{
     using (var amazonRepo = new AmazonProductCompetitivePriceRepository(uow))
     {
          amazonProductCompetitivePrice.AmazonProduct = amazonProduct;
          amazonRepo.InsertOrUpdate(amazonProductCompetitivePrice);
     }
          uow.Commit();
}

  public void InsertOrUpdate(AmazonProductCompetitivePrice amazonProductCompetitivePrice)
    {
        if (amazonProductCompetitivePrice.Id == default(int))
        {
            // New entity
            context.AmazonProductCompetitivePrices.Add(amazonProductCompetitivePrice);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(amazonProductCompetitivePrice).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Thats everything.. and thanks for the help!!

Comment: How do you save the entity?

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly the problem -- you can't save it the item is already there, you have to modify the existing item.  In order to modify an item you need "custom" code OR you have to read in the original entity and modify that before the framework can save it.

Comment: Please, show the full code sample: the retrieval, the update and the changes saving.

Comment: I made an edit with the other changes where i retrieve.. and save

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
amazonProductCompetitivePrice.AmazonProduct = amazonProduct;
```

**adds** `amazonProduct` instance to context implicitly. Because that instance was retrieved with different instance of context, current instance thinks, that it is new `AmazonProduct`. You should attach it instead, something like this:

```
if (amazonProductCompetitivePrice.AmazonProduct != null && amazonProductCompetitivePrice.AmazonProduct.Id != 0)
{
  context.Entry(amazonProductCompetitivePrice.AmazonProduct).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

Another way: you can set foreign key property only for `amazonProductCompetitivePrice` instead of navigation property.

Comment: the amazonProduct exists in the database already.  I just want to add a amazonProductCompeteitivePrice with a foreign key to the amazonProduct i retrieved from the database.  If that makes sense? :/

Comment: > the amazonProduct exists in the database already - yes, but the **context** instance, used for saving changes, considers `amazonProduct` like **new** item.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I spent a whole day to find what is wrong. And the note about related object retrieved in different context made me happy!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem
first of all I Deleted

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

annotation from my entity class.
then, I dropped the table from my sql server manually and again used
     `update-database -Verbose`
in `NuGet` package manager Console.
now, it works!