# Is EntityState.Unchanged enough for not saving?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When the user closes the editing window for a single entity object he is asked whether he wants to save the changes he made.

In case of 'yes' I call

```
DataContext.SaveChanges()
```

In case of 'no' I set

```
DataContext.Entry(myObject).State = EntityState.Unchanged
```

Is the latter enough or can it lead to a big screwup since the changed values of myObject are still changed somewhere in the background?

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479933/

Comment: Maybe it matters that I use WPF (TextBox, DatePicker, etc) and Bindings on the DependencyProperties. But when I open an entry editing window, change some values, close it without saving (via setting .State = EntityState.Unchanged) and reopen it again the old values are in there not the edited ones. How does that fit together with the link you provided me?

Comment: I assume, that you are using entity framework model to bind controls - is that correct? This is not good idea to allow your domain model be used on "frontend" page. You should use simple DTO, and pass those values to service layer.

Comment: @Piotr I don't fully get the question. I bind to properties of the objects in the Entity Framework data model (.edmx). For me to clear things can you link to a simple example where DTO is used?

Comment: Here is SOF with DTO description : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object

Comment: Understood. Well I register a normal DependencyProperty in all editing windows. I thought this would be a best practice with WPF and Entity Framework... However the confusion of my original comment on this question still stands...